# Using the Kramers-Kronig (Hilbert) transform in Python via scipy or sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, numerical-integration, lmfit

I am trying to use the Kramers-Kronig algorithm to transform the real and imaginary contributions to the anomalous scattering factor from a diffraction anomalous fine structure (DAFS) experiment.

I have fit a smooth curve to my experimental data using the lmfit package, and the following function:

```
`def intensity(en, phi, beta, I0=1, slope=0, Ioff=0, fprime=-1, fsec=1):
    costerm = np.cos(phi) + beta*fprime
    sinterm = np.sin(phi) + beta*fsec
    return I0 * (costerm**2 + sinterm**2) + slope*en + Ioff`
```

I have found minimised values of the listed parameters in the function, and used them to calculate an initial guess for f' according to:

```
`def f1_guess(f2, I, I0, phi, beta, Ioff):
    f1_guess = (1/beta) * (np.sqrt(((I-Ioff)/I0) - (math.sin(phi)+(beta*f2))) - math.cos(phi)) 
    return f1_guess`
```

I am now trying to use the Kramers-Kronig relation to transform this initial f' guess to an f" that can then be put back into the lmfit process to model the intensity, and subsequently calculate the fine structure. I have tried a few things, including the scipy.fftpack, as well as the scipy.integrate and sympy.integrate packages.

The issue I am facing is that I need to calculate the KK transform over a **finite** energy range, I.E. instead of the following:

[image]

I should do something more like the function below, by taking out the known atomic lineshape f"a(E) and integrating over my experimental energy range:

[image]

However, I am struggling to distinguish between E' and E (or omega' and omega) - I don't know how they are different from each other - and so I am unsure of how to specify these values in script format in such a way that I can accurately evaluate this integral.

Does anyone know how I might be able to transfer my f' to f", and iterate through my lmfit model until the 4 parameters (I0,Ioff,beta,phi) and the f"/f' fine structure functions stabilise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since this is primarily focused on numerical computation, you might have better luck asking on scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: I found http://people.exeter.ac.uk/sh481/kramers-kronig-relations.html useful for perfoming KK transforms in Python. However, this was for calculating the real part of the refractive index from an extinction coefficient, so over a wide energy range. It seems to me that you need a clearer handle on the physics/maths before trying to implement something otherwise what is suggested could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is maybe a little off-point for Stackoverflow, but for resonant X-ray scattering (including DAFS) in particular and other cases in optics where one might need to do a KK transform for a signal that might be a small change (your `chi` - a perturbation) from a larger signal, one can use a Differential KK transform.

That is, `f'` and `f''` are causal pairs and can either be calculated and tabulated -- and that can be over an "effectively infinite" range of frequencies/energies.  For X-ray data and in Python, you can get causal pairs from XrayDB: (see https://xraypy.github.io/XrayDB/ and specifically
https://xraypy.github.io/XrayDB/python.html#xraydb.f1_chantler).

With that known-to-be-causal pair, you can then do a differential KK transform.  To do this in Python, see https://xraypy.github.io/xraylarch/xafs_diffkk.html which also includes some links to background literature (disclosure: I am the lead developer).